# Oauth 2.0 -- WSO2 Identity server as authentication server--Issue generating access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

I am facing an issue with the oauth access token generation using WSO2 identity server as authentication server.The access token is not getting generated.

I have followed the steps in the below url - 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/09/article-how-to-generate-api-manager-access-tokens-using-multi-factor-authentication/
Instead of the second level of yahoo authentication, I have included my customized AuthServer authentication.This AuthServer code is responsible of handling the OAuth 2.0 tokens and clients details.

### Program flow

1. I have an html which has a link on click of which hits the below url:-

   ```
   https://localhost:8244/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CeYYVyMbL2CAfoelSlUlZfFrwSQa&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/ClientProj/redirect.html
   ```

   The client_id here is the client_id of the application in the API manager store.The redirect uri is the url of my sample client.
2. In the response header of the above request I am recieving the authorize code.This authorize code is used to get the actual access token as below request(POST)

[image: The Postman screenshot of the request]

Please help with a solution.

Comment: This is the url for fteching the access token using the authorize code recieved above.                                                https://localhost:8244/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=grZIGN&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/ClientProj/redirect.html.But the error recieved is invalid grant type.

Comment: The response is -- {
  "error_description": "Provided Authorization Grant is invalid",
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use: 'grant_type': 'authorization_code' ?

Example (Python):

```
 payload = { 'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': str(code), 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/resources/oauth2Callback'} 
    urllib.urlencode(payload) 
    headers = { 'application' : 'x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=verify) 

  # prepare lookup of token using code as input
    url  = "https://myserver.red.com:9443/token"
    payload = { 'key': client_id, 'secret': client_secret, 'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': str(code) }
    urllib.urlencode(payload)
    headers = { 'application' : 'x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I am getting the authorization code using this ...https://localhost:8244/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CeYYVyMbL2CAfoelSlUlZfFrwSQa&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8443/ClientProj/redirect.html ...After that this is the url I used for getting the access token using authorization.....https://localhost:8244/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=ezIBfC&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/ClientProj/redirect.html

Comment: In the section above, observe the Token request tested with WSO2 (in Python language)

Comment: Hi...I checked the python snippet above..everything seems to be same as I tried
Also With google as my identity provider in WSO2 Identity server,I am getting the same error.

These are my values--
code=4/1noN-MgU8x2qWkC0xspuCLFToq2SPVflMF9qTtcZWSQ
grant_type=authorization_code
client_secret=xcLrZa6w9HnUVSPTSoc5t6d02VQa
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/edusecure/oauth2client
client_id=EAVNy9f1WAH7uNI06Lvvn2CLEpIa

And my token request url is https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: Is this url different from https://localhost:8244/token ? 
(9443 is the port where WSO2 IS resides and 8244 is the port where the API published in API manager is exposed.
Eg.https://10.100.214.234:8244/getPersonById/1.0/persons)

I have tried both the above urls..same effect only..Invalid grant type error

Comment: The /token is always at the WSO2 server side, as an example it looks like this: https://myserver.red.com:9443/token. Please check the WSO2 Service provider setup. 
HTTP screen to trigger the initial login and callback 
https://myserver.red.com:9443/oauth2/authorize?key=xxxxxx&secret=xxxxxxxxxx">

Configiration At WSO2 Oauth 2.0 service provider: 
Callback URL:   http://localhost:8244/resources/oauth2client
Allowed Grant Types:   Code, Implicit
Access Token Url:   https://myserver.red.com:9443/oauth2/token
Authorize Url   https://myserver.red.com:9443/oauth2/authorize